# Matlab: I have limited memory, are the alternate solutions for reading in data from a video?

Tags: matlab, memory, video-processing

I am currently having a problem with matlab in that when I try and read in some data from a video I am presented with an error:

> ??? Not enough memory available for 990 frames.

I have enough memory available for reading about 100 frames or so.

I say alternate solutions in the title as I would assume the obvious answer would be to buy more memory. Are there any other ways of reading these frames and processing them? For example I thought that perhaps I may be able to read in a frame at a time via a loop and resize the video frame in order to use less memory (or do this via an alternate program)? The video is pretty memory intensive at 1024x1024. However by downscaling I am worried that I will be losing valuable data from the video.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

ps. Current code:

```
vid = VideoReader('video.avi');
frames = read(vid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read spesific frame(s) by giving the indices instead of reading all of the frames into the memory as given in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/videoreader.read.html).

```
frames = read(vid); %# Read all
frames = read(vid, index); %# Read only the specified frames
```

Example

```
frames = read(vid, [1 50]); %# Read the first 50 frames
```

Comment: I have tried this, but ideally I need to be able to process all of the video at once. Do you think this is possible given my current memory?

Comment: I don't think so. By the way, why do you need to have all the video?

Comment: Ah ok. Well 'need' was probably the wrong word, may just be me being lazy! If I need (need used correctly here!) to process to whole video, should I apply it in sections? As I'm writing this I'm pretty much answering my own question now as I'm sure you'll say stop being lazy and do it. Thanks for this btw :)

Comment: Yes, sure. You should read it in blocks of frames. And you may need to read overlapping frames if you need some adjacent frames to process.